# At what time did Nachshon enter the Sea?

Tags: passover, miracle, yam-suf

The scene of Kriat Yam Suf seems to extend at least over a couple days with the pursuit of the Egyptians beginning the day before and the "East Wind" blowing all of the succeeding night and Kriat Yam Suf actually occurring the next day. Presumably the Sea Split minutes after Nachshon entered as this is how long it would have taken for its height to reach his neck.

What traditions are about brought down about exactly when —at what time— the nes occurred?

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood the question.... The Chizkuni writes that the Egyptians weren't used to see a pillar of fire, because they only saw darkness (Shemot 14:24). Similary, the Daat Zkenim writes "this verse describes what happened on the seventh night of Passover." So, I guess it happened at night?